# Trying to connect local wordpress site to a remote db

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a site at my job that has only been maintained by 1-2 developers for a while but as more developers are being added to it we want to implement git. The workflow we're looking for has everyone using a local copy that is connected to the same remote database. We can all push and pull code as needed while any database changes would be shared that way.

I'm running into a weird issue where many files are refusing to load or clicking on any link results in a redirect to the xampp dashboard.

I downloaded xampp and created a directory in htdocs called local_test. I downloaded all the sites files into that directory with ftp. Grabbed the dbs info from the host and whitelisted the outside ip address on the host.
I went into wp-config.php and changes all the db values so it connect correctly. Plus I added:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'localhost/local_test/');
define('WP_HOME', 'localhost/local_test/');
```

At first I was convinced it was a db issue, but I can connect to the database remotely just fine using mysql workbench so I doubt it's that. The footer and the header show up, just not much of the content in between and like I said whenever I click on a link it redirect to the generic xampp dashboard.

Comment: I would make sure to run through all the steps listed here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL Only thing that comes to mind is your  xampp apache config doesn't allow .htaccess to do its thing and wordpress needs the rules to function correctly.

Comment: thank you, it was the .htaccess file